# ggplot2 throws error inside function, but not outside of function

Tags: r, function, dictionary, ggplot2

**UPDATE:**  In response to a very reasonable comment about code readability, I have restructured the code blocks.

I am attempting to map Census data for each tract in Colorado and I have encountered something that I don't know how to explain.  (The shapefile can be found [here](http://www.census.gov/geo/maps-data/data/tiger-line.html), and the Summary File 1 data was pulled via the [Census API](http://www.census.gov/developers/).)  After wrestling with the data, I successfully plotted total population with the following code:

```
#Set theme for histograms
theme_hist <- list(theme(panel.grid.minor = element_blank(),
                        panel.grid.major = element_blank(),
                        panel.background = element_blank(),
                        plot.background = element_blank(),
                        panel.border = element_blank(),
                        plot.title = element_text(size=22)))

#Plot map
pop_dist<-ggplot(aes(x=long,y=lat,group=group,fill=as.numeric(tot_pop)),data=co_mapd) + 
            geom_polygon(colour='white',size=.2) + 
            coord_equal() + 
            theme_opts + 
            labs(title='Distribution of Population') +
            scale_fill_gradient2(low='#ECE7F2',mid='#A6BDDB',high='#3300CC',
                                 midpoint=median(as.numeric(co_mapd$tot_pop)))
#ggsave('co_tract_pop_2010_map.png')

#Plot histogram
pop_hist<-ggplot(aes(x=as.numeric(tot_pop),group=group,fill=as.numeric(tot_pop)),data=co_mapd) + 
            geom_histogram() + 
            theme_hist +
            xlab('Population Bins') +
            scale_fill_gradient2(low='#ECE7F2',mid='#A6BDDB',high='#3300CC',
                                 midpoint=median(as.numeric(co_mapd$tot_pop)))
#ggsave('co_tract_pop_2010_hist.png')

#Throw plots on a single canvas
grid.arrange(pop_dist,pop_hist)
```

This generated the map and histogram plots below:
[image: First Output]
[image]

I thought this was perfect for what I was trying to do, but I have many more variables.  A function would be useful.  So, here is my function:

```
 map_var<-function(data,var,ttl){
        dist<-ggplot(aes(x=long,y=lat,group=group,fill=var),data=data) +  
        geom_polygon(colour='white',size=.2) + 
                coord_equal() + 
        theme_opts + 
        labs(title=ttl) +
        scale_fill_gradient2(low='#ECE7F2',mid='#A6BDDB',high='#3300CC',
                                 midpoint=median(data$var))

        hist<-ggplot(aes(x=var,group=group,fill=var),data=data) + 
        geom_histogram() + 
        theme_hist +
                xlab('Bins') +
                scale_fill_gradient2(low='#ECE7F2',mid='#A6BDDB',high='#3300CC',
                                midpoint=median(data$var))

        grid.arrange(dist,hist)
        }

    map_var(co_mapd,tot_pop,'Distribution of Population')
```

Seems like it should work because I tried to mirror exactly what I had done outside of my function wrapper.  I literally copy and pasted, and just changed the elements where function parameters came into play.  However, it ends up throwing the following error instead:

```
Error in data.frame(x = c(-107.48212, -107.482115, -107.482062, -107.48206,  : 
  arguments imply differing number of rows: 748351, 0
```

I should also mention that prior to running it through the function, I converted all relevant columns to numeric because as.numeric() within the function was giving me some issues.

In any event, I am not clear on why the arguments would imply a differing number of rows within the function, but not when the plotting code stands alone.  It makes me think that something funky is going on with access to appropriate environments, but I am not sure what.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

**UPDATE:** I also tried to go the aes_string route (which I was previously unaware of so thank you).  Either that wasn't the issue, or I have misapplied the technique.

```
map_var<-function(data,var,ttl,coord_x,coord_y,group='group'){
    dist<-ggplot(aes_string(x=coord_x,y=coord_y,group=group,fill=var),data=data) + 
            geom_polygon(colour='white',size=.2) + 
            coord_equal() + 
            theme_opts + 
            labs(title=ttl) +
            scale_fill_gradient2(low='#ECE7F2',mid='#A6BDDB',high='#3300CC')

    hist<-ggplot(aes(x=var,group=group,fill=var),data=data) +
            geom_histogram() + 
            theme_hist +
            xlab('Bins') +
            scale_fill_gradient2(low='#ECE7F2',mid='#A6BDDB',high='#3300CC')

    grid.arrange(dist,hist)
    }

map_var(co_mapd,var='tot_pop',ttl='Distribution of Population',coord_x='long',coord_y='lat')
```

This version throws the following exception...

```
Don't know how to automatically pick scale for object of type function. Defaulting to continuous
Error in data.frame(x = function (x, y = NULL, na.rm = FALSE, use)  : 
  arguments imply differing number of rows: 0, 748351
```

I am still not clear on what argument I am using that implies anything other than the full data.frame (in addition to being unclear why it only matters inside of a function).

**UPDATE (8/20)**:  I am adding an updated code block to incorporate the eval() suggestion.

```
map_var<-function(data,var,ttl,coord_x,coord_y,group='group'){
    dist<-ggplot(aes_string(x=eval(coord_x),y=eval(coord_y),group=eval(group),fill=eval(var)),data=data) + 
            geom_polygon(colour='white',size=.2) + 
            coord_equal() + 
            theme_opts + 
            labs(title=eval(ttl)) +
            scale_fill_gradient2(low='#ECE7F2',mid='#A6BDDB',high='#3300CC')

    hist<-ggplot(aes(x=eval(var),group=eval(group),fill=eval(var)),data=data) +
            geom_histogram() + 
            theme_hist +
            xlab('Bins') +
            scale_fill_gradient2(low='#ECE7F2',mid='#A6BDDB',high='#3300CC')

    grid.arrange(dist,hist)
    }

map_var(co_mapd,var='tot_pop',ttl='Distribution of Population',coord_x='long',coord_y='lat')
```

I wanted to share explicitly in case I executed poorly.  I am afraid, however, that it has not changed the exception.

Comment: Try using `aes_string` in your function (and of course pass strings to it).

Comment: Nice code but very hard to read. See http://google-styleguide.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/Rguide.xml for some guides on how to write more legible code, which is very important when soliciting feedback. Think about breaking your lines after the `+` symbol for legibility. I even go so far as to break lines at each new argument (after the `,`), sometimes.

Comment: You still need to pass `aes_string()` characters. The code you posted has, e.g., `aes_string(x = coord_x)`. This needs to be changed to `aes_string(x = 'coord_x')`.

Comment: Am I not fulfilling this requirement via strings in the function call (the last line)?

Comment: Yes and no. If you want to pass strings like this you need to wrap coord_x etc in eval. So, for example, the first line of ```map_var``` should be ```aes_string(x = eval(coord_x), ...```

Comment: No dice I am afraid (unless I did something wrong).  Does anyone know what this exception actually indicates?  All of the examples I have found provide patches that seem to be shots in the dark or reflect acquired practical knowledge.  I have not yet seen an explanation of what the problem actually is...

Comment: you failed to change `aes()` to `aes_string()` in the hist plot; also, ignore the `eval()` thing, it's nonsense. Generally speaking, working on a _minimal_ example helps you nail down the exact problem more easily.

Comment: Eureka!  I knew it was something stupid (well, at some stage it would be).  The aes_string business was new to me.  Also, you are correct *baptiste*, eval() was unnecessary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For those who may encounter this problem at a later time, this worked beautifully:

```
map_var<-function(data,var,ttl,coord_x,coord_y,group='group'){
    dist<-ggplot(aes_string(x=coord_x,y=coord_y,group=group,fill=var),data=data) + 
            geom_polygon(colour='white',size=.2) + 
            coord_equal() + 
            theme_opts + 
            labs(title=ttl) +
            scale_fill_gradient2(low='#ECE7F2',mid='#A6BDDB',high='#3300CC')

    hist<-ggplot(aes_string(x=var,group=group,fill=var),data=data) +
            geom_histogram() + 
            theme_hist +
            xlab('Bins') +
            scale_fill_gradient2(low='#ECE7F2',mid='#A6BDDB',high='#3300CC')

    grid.arrange(dist,hist)
    }

map_var(co_mapd,var='tot_pop',ttl='Distribution of Population',coord_x='long',coord_y='lat')
```

Hat tip to *baptiste* and *Roland* in the comments above.  Many thanks.